# Laravel whereBetween in two columns

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

i need to select products from DB by `whereBetween`.
I have two `double` type columns in database, `price` and `newprice`.
`Price` field is required and `newprice` is 0 by default. Admin writes `newprice` if there is any discounts on that product.

Now my problem is it that i need to select from DB with `whereBetween` by `price` if `newprice == 0` and by `newprice` if `newprice != 0`.
In a word filter by `newprice` if it is written, and by `price` if `newprice` is 0 by default.

Here is my code.

```
$from = (int)$request->priceFrom;
$to = (int)$request->priceTo;

$products = Product::whereIn('category_id', $childCategories)->orWhere('category_id', $category->id)->where('publish', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
$products->whereBetween('price',array($from,$to))->orWhereBetween('newprice',array($from,$to));
$products = $products->paginate(15);
```

It doesn't works correctly ofc. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do something like this using laravels parameter grouping

```
$products->where(function($query){
     $query->where('new_price', 0)
     ->whereBetween('price', [$from, $to]);
})->orWhere(function($query){
     $query->where('new_price', '>', 0)
     ->whereBetween('new_price', [$from, $to]);
})->paginate(15);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks fro response, i need pagination too that is why this method doesn't work for me :(

Comment: @SabaTandashvili i updated my answer. you can check it out.